# Does my proof that if $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$ then $\lim_{x\to c}|f(x)|=|L|$ work?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I'm retrying exercise $4.2.14$ from the Bartle and Sherbert Real Analysis Book:

> Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R},$ let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$, and let $c\in\mathbb{R}$ be a cluster point of $A$. If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f$ exists, and if $|f|$ denotes the function defined for $x\in A$ by $|f|(x):=|f(x)|,$ prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}|f|=\left|\lim_{x\to c} f\right|$.

I've done this proof previously using the Sequential Criterion for Limits, and I'm trying it now using the definition of the limit. Does the solution I have below work? If not, anything I can do to improve?

**Proof:** Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f$ exists, suppose $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f=L\in\mathbb{R},$ and suppose $\epsilon>0.$ Then there exists some $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that if $x\in A$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta,$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$ Assuming $x\in A$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta,$ it follows by the triangle inequality that $||f(x)|-|L||\leq|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$ Therefore, we conclude based on the definition of the limit of a function that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}|f|=|L|=\left|\lim_{x\to c} f\right|.\blacksquare$

Comment: Seems exactly right to me, yes

Comment: For clarity, I would change your first "suppose" into a "let" and put the second "suppose" in a new sentence.